# Excel Macro - Search Range of Cell for 0, then return "empty" cell

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time using this forum, and my VBA skill is not very well developed. I hope someone can help.

I have two columns of data, **Column A** and **Column B**.

**Column A** - Returns a sequential "month-year" or 0. If spreadsheet current date (=now()) is less than say Feb, then the cell for February returns 0.

**Column B** -  I want this column to check each cell in Column A. If Column A cell has a date identifier, I want this to be placed in Column B. If Column A has a 0 identifier, I want Column B to return an "empty" cell.

Reason why I am doing this is I am graphing a bar chart. When I trick the program into making an empty cell (x-axis) the graph does not show any data for that month (which is what I want). Trying to make a dynamic graph, but I have no experience in VBA (only C programming =/).

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this. `=IF(A1=0,"",A1)` and drag the formula down.

Comment: Hi Ripster, I tried this but "" does not return a true empty space, so 0 will be shown on my x-axis graph. I think need to use VBA and assign =blank command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA (or even formulas) to do this.
Highlight Column A (the entire column), copy it.
Highlight Column B (the entire column, right click, Paste Special, select values and number formats, okay.
Highlight Column B again. Press Ctrl+H, Type 0 (or failing that it might be 00/01/1900) in the 'find what', leave the 'replace with' one blank. Tick Match entire cell contents. Click replace all.
Done.

Comment: Hi Phil, I see your point but this is not what I am after. I want to make a dynamic bar chart which will last one year. At the moment Column A changes according to one cell link to Now() command (i.e. current date).

Comment: So if the current date on the spreadsheet is Aug 2013 and my start date is June 2013, the x-axis values will be June 2013 and July 2013, with the rest being 0s. Now, if i trick Column B to return an empty space the graph will not plot the 0s. Basically I want the bar chart to update as time passes.

Comment: Instead of special paste, just paste. Then repeat the Ctrl+H bit. Column B will retain the formulas from column A. Cheers.

Comment: I see but I want the chart to update automatically. Everytime I open the spreadsheet the spreadsheet will check the current date and update accordingly. I think I need a macro for this.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.
I'll leave you with the VBA code, to get empty cells, as that's what you were after originally.
Sub Main() : Columns("A").Copy : Columns("B").PasteSpecial : 
Columns("B").Replace What:=0, Replacement:=Empty :End Sub

Comment: Basically if I can get column B to search (automatically each time I open spreadsheet) Column A for a date identifier and 0 and return either the date identifier or EMPTY cell for 0 then this will solve my problem =)!

Comment: YOU.ARE.AWESOME...slight tweak though if I want to reference a couple cells in the column instead of using the whole column, how do I do so. Your macro works well, but i want to only target some cells within the column, not the whole column.

Comment: Range("A1:A15").copy   etc.

Comment: By the way. If you put whatever code you're writing into the ThisWorkbook module and find the event Workbook_Open. It will run automatically when you open the workbook. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying for an empty space (which would be impossible, as there's a formula in that cell), use an error condition.
Use this formula, and copy down:

```
=IF(A1=0,NA(),A1)
```

This will return the error condition *#NA!* and Excel will leave the column blank

The other way would be to have a dynamic range for the chart data - I have a chart that will adjust to 5,6 or 7 days, depending on the data returned for the week. The **Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels** is set to a named range (`='Sample.xlsx'!LastWeekRange`) and the range checks the data, and returns the appropriate number of cells.
LastWeekRange is defined in Name Manager as `=OFFSET(Data!$A$3,0,0,IF(Data!$F$9>0,7,IF(Data!$F$8>0,6,5)))`, which returns **A3:A7** if there's nothing in *F8*, **A3:A8** if there is something in *F8* but not in *F9*, and **A3:A9** if there is something in *F9*.